# I am unable to run any Github project on my laptop & receive the following error on running the project

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Whenever I download a **Flutter Project** from **Git-hub** and try to run it, I receive the following error message.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The current version of my Android Studio is: *4.0.1*
And the Gradle version is: *distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip.*

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
```

comment this code in your settings.gradle file